# UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height and UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width are both 0

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I recently did and update to my Xamarin iOS project and I use to be able to call the following code to retrieve the screen width and height:

```
if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight)
    return new RectangleF(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.X, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Y, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width);
```

However now with the update the bounds are set using CGRect so my code has changed to this:

```
if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight)
    return new CGRect(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.X, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Y, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width);
```

Now when I try to do this the height and width returns 0. I've tried to create a new project and try the same thing but I run into the same problem. How can I now retrieve the width and height of the main screen?

Comment: Are you using Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio

Comment: in which method of the lifecycle are you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it's a bug in the Visual Studio plugin, it's been reported before: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/80994/#Comment_80994

The workaround is to use Xamarin Studio (on your Mac) in the meantime.

It would be appreciated if you could file a bug at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com with your project so that we can fix it.